# SwiftUI: i’m trying to make an app that shows different cards and their attributes, but I keep getting errors

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, mvvm

I mainly keep getting these four errors:

> Initializer 'init (_:)' requires that 'Binding' conform to
> 'StringProtocol

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to
> expected argument type 'String'

> Cannot convert value of type '[Card]'
> to expected argument type 'Binding'

> Generic parameter 'C' could
> not be inferred

This is the code for my Content View were the errors are:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = CardViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
           NavigationView{
               ScrollView{
                   ForEach(viewModel.cards, id: \.self) { card in 
                       HStack {
                           Image(card.cardName)
                               .resizable()
                               .scaledToFit()
                               .cornerRadius(90)
                               .padding(.horizontal)
                           
                           Spacer()
                           
                           VStack(alignment: .trailing){ 
                               Text(card.cardName)
                               Text(card.type)
                               Text(card.atk)
                               Text(card.def)
                           }
                       }
                       .frame(height: 80)
                   }
               }
                .navigationTitle("Yu-Gi-Oh!")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
```

This is the code for my View model:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension ContentView {
    @MainActor class CardViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var cards: [Card] = [Card(cardName:"Obelisk", level: 10, tpye: "Divine", atk: 4000, def: 4000), Card(cardName: "Slifer", level: 10, tpye: "Divine", atk: nil, def: nil ), Card(cardName: "F.A. Dawn Dragster", level: 7, tpye: "Light", atk: 0, def: 2000), Card(cardName: "Timestar Magician", level: 4, tpye: "Dark", atk: 2400, def: 1200)]
    }
}
```

This is the code for my swift file with my structure:

```
import Foundation

struct Card: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var cardName: String
    var level: Int?
    var tpye: String
    var atk: Int?
    var def: Int?
}
```

I’m trying to make an app that uses view models to show different cards and they’re attributes.

Comment: try this:
 `Text("\(card.atk)")` and `Text("\(card.def)")`, also change `var tpye: String` to `var type: String`
 in your `struct Card`, and use `let id = UUID()`
 
And importantly, read the **basics of SwiftUI**, see for example: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Optionals nor `Int` on `Text` that's causing one of the errors

The comment from workingdog doesn't fix it, it will throw the following error

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

His comment would work if the `Int` wasn't an Optional. Assuming that you want to keep the `Int` as Optional you must provide a default value.

I marked where you must provide a default value, the way it's coded must be the default value must be a `Int` if you want to display a string you could do something like this instead of providing a default `Int`

```swift
Text("\(card.atk == nil ? "N/A" : String(card.atk!))")
```

Below it's the view with the default `Int`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = CardViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(viewModel.cards, id: \.self) { card in
                    HStack {
                        Image(card.cardName)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .cornerRadius(90)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                            Text(card.cardName)
                            Text(card.tpye)
                            Text("\(card.atk ?? 0)") // Add default value here
                            Text("\(card.def ?? 0)") // Add default value here
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 80)
                }
            }
             .navigationTitle("Yu-Gi-Oh!")
         .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }
}
```

I'll provide the same recommendation as workingdog did, get to know the SwiftUI basics developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

**NOTE:** The entire code that you provided complies and executes. If you still get errors it's not from that code.